# Multitouch-gestures with wxWidgets 3.0?

Tags: wxwidgets, gesture, multi-touch

Since Google does not really show any usable results: are mutlitouch-gestures available in wxWidgets 3.0? If yes: what classes are used for this or where can I find the related manual?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`3.0` no, but from `3.1.1` you might find [wxGestureEvent](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_gesture_event.html) useful.

There is also an [open PR](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/pull/649) for "raw touch events".